# How to add relief to this cookie

Tags: modeling, normal-map

I'm modeling a cookie, but was wondering how to add the relief to the chocolate..I read there's multiple options, like bump and normal mapping, but I'd prefer to try and do some real displacement instead of rendering 'magic'.

Should I model this myself somehow? Or can I use the example image to do some work for me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a displacement map, you can use that map in a displacement modifier to deform the real geometry.

If you don't have a map nor the model, then you have to make either one of them.

Manual modeling can be a bit more tricky because you have to handle the topology.
As for the map, you can maybe find it online, or use a software like [Materialize](http://www.boundingboxsoftware.com/materialize/) or [AwesomeBump](https://sourceforge.net/projects/awesomebump.mirror/) to generate a displacement map from your photo, and then you only have to make sure you have enough subdivision for the displacement modifier to make effect.

Comment: I don't have one, just the example image..so should I make the map myself? Won't that be the same as modeling it?

Comment: it's not exactly the same, if you don't have a map nor the model, then you have to make either one of them. Manual modeling can be a bit more tricky because you have to handle the topology. As for the map, you can maybe find it online, or use a software like Materialize or AwesomeBump to generate a displacement map from your photo, and then you only have to make sure you have enough subdivision for the displacement modifier to make effect.

Comment: thanks, I'll check out that software, or dive into making my own displacement map